# Issue on Running Affix With Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble on using Bootstrap 3 Affix. As you can see at [This Deno](http://www.bootply.com/4lEwQDtZqX) I would like to keep the row always on the top of the page on scrolling down but the page jump and stops as soon as the row appeaser on the top and the row it self also disappears!

here is the code I am using for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myAffix").affix({
        offset: { 
            top: 125
        }
    });
});
```

and html is

```
<div class="row" id="myAffix">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

The issue is more obvious on small screens when scrolling down! Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix the navbar at the top you don't need to use `Affix`. The easiest way is to add the class `.navbar-fixed-top` to the `navbar`, then apply some padding to the `body`.

Here's a new bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/FgQaY8ZIjg

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="main-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  padding-top:70px;
}
```